# Flutter: Hot Reload gets stuck in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

**UPDATE:**
I tried with another clean new project. Hot reload works fine.

Every time I perform a hot reload on my VS Code, the hot reload gets stuck with the following message. Anyone knows the problem?

[image: Error Message]

These are the things that I have done.

1. Terminal: Ran flutter doctor -- (everything ok, except a warning sign of a little bit outdated Xcode. I'm using Xcode 11.1.0)
2. Restarted VS
3. Restarted the entire machine
4. Running on both simulator and physical iPad

These are my specs:

1. Macbook Pro Early 2015
2. macOS Mojave
3. VS Code 1.52.1 (latest)
4. Flutter extension v3.18.1 (latest)
5. Dart v3.18.1 (latest)
6. Xcode 11.1.0 (not latest)

Debug console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad Pro (9.7-inch) in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           82.4s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51095/_Dfl55VaXyE=/ws
```

Comment: does it work if you run `flutter run` command from the command line and press `r` key?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work as well. The strange thing is that when I start the app > make a small change (I just change the color of a container) > save > gets reloaded > change to another color > reload gets stuck

Comment: do you see anything suspicious if you run `flutter -v run`? (`-v` stands for "verbose") - what do you see when you press `r` and `R` key?

Comment: Suspicious stuff:
[+2007 ms] This is taking a long time; will now check for paused isolates.
Press r again:
[+31225 ms] Ignoring terminal input: "r" because we are busy.

Comment: However, at the beginning, there's one suspicious looking thing ->
 Running with unsound null safety
[        ] For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Comment: `Running with unsound null safety` is OK, what if you press `R` key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227478/discussion-between-fendy3d-and-pskink).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Listview.builder or Grideview.builder then comment it out or remove that code block.

Sometimes it happens because of the unbounded height problem of listview.builder and hot reload get stuck and fail to compile the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me... I had an unfinished Listview code where I forgot to add the itemCount parameter, once I rectified it, Hot Reload started working as it should... Thanks @Mashood

Answer (score 2):

I was try open DevTools in the browser and press Hot reload button and it's working!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which Flutter version you were using but you could be running into a case of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84347 which is related to isolates getting somehow stuck during hot reload.
I don't know the `audioplayers` library but I assume it uses an isolate in the background.

Answer (score -4):

Delete the emulator and run `flutter clean` from the terminal.
Then create the emulator again and it will fix the issue.

Comment: I did start the emulator from afresh, didn't work. Plus, this problem happens on physical device as well.

Answer (score -5):

Run `flutter clean` and run your project again and see if that solves the problem.